# How can I generically cast an enum?

Tags: c#, parsing, enums

I'm trying to solve a simple parsing problem and I elected to use enums to encode lists of choices.

The input data is straight ascii text, broken into blocks with unique header and non-unique identifiers where the data is.  I'm able to write pretty general symbolizing methods without providing any context as to the data meaning and deal with it once it's returned.

Doing this with strings is no problem.  I just pass a List in and away we go.

I can't figure out the syntax to generalize an enum, and I could use some help.  I could also be far too locked into imperative thinking and missing an easy answer to this.

Here's the code I'm having a hard time with

```
private void parseToEnums(Enum returnEnum, string searchBlock, string startIDText,
                          string endIDText, string startText, string endText)
{
    string ourSearchBlock = searchBlock;
    int endIDidx = ourSearchBlock.IndexOf(endIDText);

    while (ourSearchBlock.IndexOf(startText) != -1)
    {
        if (ourSearchBlock.Length == searchBlock.Length)
        {
            // first pass, trim off the region where the start text isn't valid
            ourSearchBlock = ourSearchBlock.Remove(endIDidx, ourSearchBlock.Length - endIDidx);
            // first pass, use the startIDtext to create a valid search zone
            // BROKEN CODE HERE
            // Neither GetType() nor typeof seem to do the right thing
            // I have tried several varieties and have tried casting the LHS in the
            // same sort of way
            // pluckText returns a string that is guaranteed to match an enum name
            returnEnum = (returnEnum.GetType()) System.Enum.Parse(typeof(returnEnum), pluckText(ourSearchBlock, startIDText, startText, endText), false);
            ourSearchBlock = ourSearchBlock.Remove(0, ourSearchBlock.IndexOf(startIDText) + startIDText.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            // this would be similar to the above after it's working
            // and is for the case where the string has multiple matches
            // within the enum, ie "red white"
            //returnList.Add(pluckText(ourSearchBlock, "", startText, endText));
        }
        ourSearchBlock = ourSearchBlock.Remove(0, ourSearchBlock.IndexOf(startText) + startText.Length);
    }

    return;
}
```

Example of what I'm doing

```
private enum Colors { red, white, green };
private enum Suits  { spades, clubs, hearts, diamonds };

// ... open files, read data, etc
// so I pass in the enum that I want my result in and some text identifiers

parseToEnum ( Colors, searchBlock, "startColorBlock", "endColorBlock", "id=" );
parseToEnum ( Suits, searchBlock, "startCardSuitsBlock", "endCardSuitsBlock", "<id=" );

// ...
```

So the idea is to use the same structure (since the inputs are the same) but use different enums for the output.

I am aware that I need to add some try/catch wrappers and general error detection into this code before too much longer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to ignore all that searching and focus on converting a `string` to an `enum`.

First, I think your method should *return* the result, not pass it as a parameter (you would need `out` for that).

Second, to pass the type of the enum to the method, you can either use a a parameter of type `Type`, or, even better, make the method generic and pass the type as a type argument.

The method could look like this:

```
T ParseEnum<T>(string s)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s, false);
}
```

You could then call it like this:

```
Colors color = ParseEnum<Colors>(someString);
```

The errors in your code are:

- `Enum` is a common base type of all `enum`s, it does not represent the type of an `enum`. That means you can't use for example `Colors` as a parameter to a method.
- You can't cast to a type known only at runtime. In other words, code like `(foo.GetType())bar` will never work.
- You can't use the `typeof` operator to get the type of a variable. You can use it to get the `Type` object for some specific type, e.g. `typeof(string)` or `typeof(T)` in a generic method with type argument `T`.
- The names of types (including `enum`s) should be in singular. That's because for example variable of type `Color` represents *one* color. Though this is only a style issue and it won't stop your code from working. But it will make your code harder to understand.

Comment: Feel free to ignore the searching :-)  If I hadn't included it, someone would have blasted me for not providing enough detail.  I like this a lot and will give it a whirl.

Comment: I also like that I could write color &= Par...; with this method.

Comment: You write that, but it probably won't work the way you want. If you want to have an `enum` that can represent several values at the same time, you have to set the values to non-overlapping binary values (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, …) and use `|` to combine them.

Comment: You raise a great point that would have occurred to me after a lot of pointless debugging ... and once upon a time I knew that.  I do want an enum to work more like a bitset and you're right, I need to treat it that was for setting and getting.